# Including image with header in php

Tags: php, image, header, include

What I am trying to achieve is to include an image with php. I am using the header png function:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Then I am including the image by jusing the include() function.

Some images are returning correctly, but most of them around 90% give the same error. The error is this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' in algemeen.png on line 103
```

The strange thing is that I have exactly the same code running on an older server and there works everything fine. Every image is returned correctly.
And I have exact the same copy of that old server running on this server, but then I recieve the errors shown above.

Does anyone know what I can do about it ?

Comment: Where is line 103?

Comment: Could you show us the include line as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [readfile](http://php.net/readfile)

```
readfile("/path/to/file.png");
```

I'm guessing the binary data in the image accidentally contains `<?` or `<?php` tags that get executed as code when using `include`.